# Unable to detect my iPhone 5s in the Develop menu of Safari 6.1.6 on Mac OS X 10.7.5

Tags: macos, ios8, safari6, safari-web-inspector

I am using Mac OS X 10.7.5 with Safari 6.1.6 and iPhone 5s with iOS 8.0.2. I am trying to remotely debug my website on my mac safari but my safari is not listing my iPhone in the develop menu.

I have already enabled web inspector in my iPhone safari settings. Any solutions please.